# React Native : react-native-geolocation

Tags: android, react-native, geolocation, android-emulator

I need to fetching location in react-native. I used `@react-native-community/geolocation`.
When `getCurrentPosition` we have option `enableHighAccuracy`.

My problem is when I run my app in `android emulator` it must change to `enableHighAccuracy: true`.

But when I run on `device` it not working and must be change to `enableHighAccuracy : false`

This is example of my code :

```
const callLocation = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
      const { longitude, latitude } = position.coords
      setLoading(false);
      setRegion({ ...region, latitude, longitude });
    },
      error => console.log(error.message),
      { 
        timeout: 20000, 
        enableHighAccuracy: true, // must change to false when run on device
        maximumAge: 1000 },
    );
  }
```

Maybe you have the same problem with me, I appreciate a lot about your help.

Comment: Permissions provided in `AndroidManifest.xml` ?

Comment: Yes, the location is running and can get latitude and longitude, the issue just about enableHighAccuracy: true

Comment: Looks like a device specific issue. Perhaps A-GPS is not supported. Found a similar issue in GH repo - https://github.com/react-native-geolocation/react-native-geolocation/issues/43

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this problem with storing `enableHighAccuracy` to state, so whenever the value for instance `false` is not working I update the value to `true` and vice versa.

```
const [enableHighAccuracy, setEnableHighAccuracy] = useState(true); // my state

const callLocation = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
      const { longitude, latitude } = position.coords
      setLoading(false);
      setRegion({ ...region, latitude, longitude });
    },
      error => {
       setEnableHighAccuracy(!enableHighAccuracy); // change when error
       console.log(error.message)
      },
      { 
        timeout: 20000, 
        enableHighAccuracy, // apply the state to this
        maximumAge: 1000 },
    );
  }
```